# Citing papers that use unpublished data that I want to publish

Tags: publications

I am getting ready to submit a method paper which describes a dataset that I had created. However, I was late getting the paper ready, and a couple of other colleagues used the dataset in their own papers, and those papers are already online (I am coauthor in them).

The other papers do not describe in detail how the dataset was constructed. I am afraid that if cite them, it might harm my chances of getting my own paper on the dataset published. Any suggestions on what would be the right thing to do?

thanks!

Comment: Is it like a cardinal sin for people in your field to publish with data set that itself has not been published? You mention "it might harm" your chance, why is that? To me (biomedical here), you data set has been formally used, pilot tested, and was deemed feasible and useful. That sounds positive to me.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I was not sure if the reviewers might look at it less positively because the dataset was already used in another paper. In hindsite, I was probably just being paranoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have at least 40 % new material you can submit your paper to journals and you should also cite the other paper without any hesitation.

Answer (score 2):

If the new paper you are submitting adds something significant on how the data was generated it should be OK to include it again and cite the other papers- it would be not formally correct to not cite them especially since you contributed the data.